# Calculate total monthly server cpu hours

Tags: linux, centos, cloud-computing

I currently have a centos 5 virtual private server. Its not maxed out. But I would like to plan to expand into the cloud from it and use the vps as a staging area at some point. How can I go about calculating monthly cpu hors and possibly total bandwidth. Its next to impossible to calculate the real cost of cloud without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send uptime and iptables -L -v output just before VPS shutdown to some static server? It's needed anyway, a.k.a. central management server.
Another solution might be any cloud compatible monitoring system.